# Use the Flex 4.6 SDK in Flash Pro CS5.5?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I have a codebase for a Flash Builder project that loads in assets from a Flash Professonal project swf, and as such, they share the same codebase to compile from (so the code in the FB project can link to MC's in the Flash Pro)

Issue is, the code I am using has Flex 4.6 code in it (namely built in JSON support). That builds fine in FB, but when I update the Flash Pro swf, I get an error, probably because I have Flex 4.6 code and Flash pro CS5.5 isn't using Flex 4.6 to compile. Is there a way in Flash pro to target Flex 4.6 as the builder?

Thanks!
-Steve

Comment: what's the error you're getting?  it's probably just a matter of including the necessary .SWCs in the .FLA

Comment: JSON isn't a Flex thing... it's a Flash Player 11.x thing. Open your publish settings in flash and make sure the "target" is set to Flash Player 11 or higher.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to get Flash Pro to use the Flex Compiler.  The Flex Compiler does a bunch of "magic" related to framework setup.  To use Flex classes in Flash Pro you'll have to perform the full Flex Framework setup yourself which I do not recommend trying.  @dtudury It's more than just adding SWCs.

Comment: @dtudury JSON is not defined

Comment: @JasonReeves I don't have the option to target 11.x...height I have in CS5.5 is 10.2

Comment: hmm.. maybe try to hook up Flash and Flex in [this way](http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000294.html) and see if maybe you get lucky and it will recognize the class.  It might not work... but it might?!?  Other than that I would suggest upgrading flash pro so they are both targeting player 11+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually found a solution for you  [Adding player 11 support to cs5](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html)

Answer (score 0):

just for your records... before 11.x you'd have to include as3corelib.swc for its JSON functionality: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

Comment: I realize this, but I'm collaborating with someone using 11.x and Flex 4.6 and their sources don't have as3corelib

Comment: and even if they did, pathing out to the JSON library your using is annoying... I'm changing my answer to "upgrade your version of flash pro" ;)

Answer (score -1):

Flex SDK 4.6 comes with complete source code under /sdk/frameworks/projects directory, as the source codes are broken into "projects", you would need to merge the projects together to get the entire framework source under one logical source tree.

Once you have this source tree created, you may add that to your Flash's compile path to gain the benefit of Flex SDK.  But if you need Flex just for mere JSON support, then the target of Flash Player 11 would be a much better solution.

Comment: -1; Flex Framework doesn't provide any JSON support; although it can make use of the Flash Player's JSON support.